# Does any one know birt report oda jdbc connection method?

Tags: java, birt

Please help me for open connection method for birt oda jdbc connectio.
I used 
birt 4.8.0
java 8.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: Hi karan, Thank you for your advice. I google this one but not found yet. :(

Comment: below is my error. Appreciate if you take a look. any advice. Thank you.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.IDriver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 ... 88 more

Comment: When you want to connect to a database using JDBC you will need a JDBC driver for that database and it looks like your missing one or haven’t configured your project properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should download the jdbc from : [https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVrtY.png)

And then, add it in your eclipse, this is my path (for example) :
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc_3.7.1.v20110905\drivers

You will need to update your eclipse connection by clicking on 'manage driver' when you edit your data source :
[image]

My version is an old one, but, it should be the same for you